# Power BI Matrix Visual Showing Row of Blank Values Even Though Source Data Does Not Have Blanks

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables one with data about franchise locations (Franchise Profile Info) and one with Award data. Each franchise location is given a certain number of awards they are allowed to give out per year. Each franchise location rolls up to a larger group depending on where in the country they are located. These tables are in a 1 to 1 relationship using Franchise ID. I am trying to create a matrix with the number of awards, total utilized, and percentage utilized rolled up to group with the ability to expand the groups and see individual locations. For some reason when I add the value fields a blank row is created. There are not any blank rows in either of the original tables so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

Franchise Profile Info table

| ID | Franchise Name | Group | Street Address | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 164 | Park's | West | 12 Park Dr. | Los Angeles | CA |
| 365 | A & J | East | 243 Whiteoak Rd | Stafford | VA |
| 271 | Otto's | South | 89 Main St. | St. Augustine | FL |

Award table

| ID | Year | TotalAwards | Utilized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 164 | 2022 | 16 | 12 |
| 365 | 2022 | 5 | 5 |
| 271 | 2022 | 22 | 17 |

This tables are in a relationship with a 1 to 1 match on ID

What I want the matrix to look like

| Group | Total Awards | Utilized | %Awards Utilized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| East | 5 | 5 | 100% |
| West | 16 | 12 | 75% |
| South | 22 | 17 | 77% |

Instead what I'm getting is this

| Group | Total Awards | Utilized | %Awards Utilized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| East | 5 | 5 | 100% |
| West | 16 | 12 | 75% |
| South | 22 | 17 | 77% |
|  | 0 | 0 | 0% |

I can't for the life of me figure out where this row is coming from. I can add in the Group and Franchise name as rows but as soon as I add any of the value columns this blank row shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You have a value on the many side that does not exist on the one side. You can read a full explanation here. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/blank-row-in-dax/